how to remove page name from dynamic url in codeigniter
from this
http://localhost/project/blog-details/hello-name
to this
http://localhost/project/hello-name
routes
$route['blog-details/(:any)'] = 'Welcome/blog_details/$1';

controller
public function blog_detail($id)
    {
        $data['EDITDATA'] = $slugdata = $this->db->get_where('blog',array('slug'=>$id,))->result_object();
        if(!empty($slugdata))
        {
            $this->load->view('blog_detail',$data);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('error');
        }
    }


blog_details != blog_detail
